# Writing A Function Using Helper Functions

Tags: functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function in Scheme that takes two strings as input and returns a list of all optimal pairs of strings. In order to do this, I know that I need to make use of the following functions that **I have already written**. The functions already written will obviously need to be used as helper functions for the function that I'm trying to write.

**1. score-chars**

This function takes two strings, and scores each character according to a scoring criteria and accumulates the result. If two characters are equal, a score of 2 is obtained, if two characters are not equal, a score of -1 is obtained, and finally, if one character is an underscore, and the other character something else, a score of -2 is obtained.

**Here is example input/output:**

```
> (score-chars "x" "x")
2

> (score-chars "x" "y")
-1

> (score-chars "x" "_")
-2

> (score-chars "Cheese" "Computer")
-3
```

**2. change-string-pairs**

This function takes two chars (a and b, say) and a list of pairs of strings as input, and returns a modified list of pairs of strings: for each string pair in the list.

Here is example input/output:

```
> (change-string-pairs "a" "b" '(("one" "two")("three" "four")("five" "six")))
(("aone" "btwo") ("athree" "bfour") ("afive" "bsix"))
```

**3. get-best-pairs**

This function takes both a scoring function (scoring function in this case will be score-chars, which is described above) and a list of pairs of strings as input and then returns a modified list of pairs of strings. The returned list will contain all the optimal string pairs from the input, scored according to the input function.

**Here is example input/output:**

```
> (get-best-pairs score-chars '(("cheese" "cake")("door" "wall")("bunny" "roof")("mouse" "house")("photo" "video")))
(("mouse" "house"))
```

Having all these functions described above that I have already written, the function that I'm trying to write using those functions will have the following:

**Input/output:**

```
> (get-all-best-pairs "many" "penny")
(("man_y" "penny") 
 ("ma_ny" "penny") 
 ("m_any" "penny") 
 ("_many" "penny"))
```

Would be really great, if I can get a rough idea of how this can be done. Also, in my functions that I have written above, I have made use of some built in Scheme functions like map, filter, append and apply.

I also am aware, that the algorithm is extremely inefficient, and is of exponential complexity. That is not of a concern to me at this time.

**I know that the first step is to write a function that will generate all possible sequence matches. Once I have this function, the rest will be easy. Hence, this is the part where I am really stuck.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have almost everything you need except for a function that can sort a list using a predicate function.

If your Scheme interpreter does not provide a sorting function, you can use one found at [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Merge_sort#Scheme) . You'll have to adapt it to take a predicate function instead of using `<=` as the default predicate function.

Your predicate function can be:

```
(define (compare-by-alignment lhs rhs)
   (<= (alignment-score-tail lhs) (alignment-score-tail rhs)))
```

You can call `merge-sort` using your list and predicate function as:

```
(merge-sort lst compare-by-alignment)
```

Comment: In R5RS and R7RS you have `sort` through [SRFI-95](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-95/srfi-95.html) and from R6RS you have [`list-sort`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-5.html).

Comment: @R Sahu What I don't understand, is why I would need to sort a list in my algorithm solution, because all I'm trying to do, is to take two strings, find all possible sequence matches by inserting underscores in appropriate places. Then after doing that, score each string pair created by using the scoring criteria. After scoring all pairs created, find the maximum score, then filter out all string pairs that are not equal to the maximum score. By doing that, I will have all the optimal string pairs.

Comment: @R Sahu So where exactly would I need to make use of sorting a list, as I can't see how it will help me in generating a solution.

Comment: @Curiosity, after you find all the possible sequence matches, which I imagine will be list, you can sort that list using the scoring criteria. Then just grab the first item from the sorted list.

Comment: @RSahu Oh okay, I see. That makes sense to do after getting all the possible sequence matches, but then the difficult part is finding all the possibilites. Once I get all the possible sequence matches, then the rest will be easy. What I'm not sure of is how to go about writing a function that will generate all the possible sequence matches, and that will return a list containing all possible sequence matches in the format of (("one" "two")("three" "four")) etc.