# Writing a scheme function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, gambit

How do I write a function that takes both a scoring function (which I've written already) and a list of pairs of strings as input (which I'm confused on how to write), and returns a modified list of pairs of strings, where the returned list should contain all the optimal string pairs from the input, scored according to the input function.

Example input:

```
'( ("hello" "b_low") ("hello_" "b_l_ow") ("hello" "_blow") ("hello" "blow") ("h_e_llo" "bl_o__w") )
```

Example output:

```
( ("hello" "b_low") ("hello_" "b_l_ow") ("hello" "_blow") )
```

**the function takes a list of pairs of strings as shown above. It also takes in a function. It uses this function that it takes in as a means to evaluate the list of pairs of strings. It then returns a list of pairs of strings containing all of the pairs of strings that had the highest match-score based on the function it was given to evaluate them with. In other words, (("hello" "b_low") ("hello_" "b_l_ow") ("hello" “_blow")) all had the same score of -3, but ("h_e_llo" “bl_o__w”)) has a score of -12, thus it is dropped from the list.**

The functions to compute alignemt:

```
(define (char-scorer char1 char2)
  (cond 
    ((char=? char1 char2) 2)
    ((or (char=? char1 #\_ ) (char=? #\_ char2)) -2)
    (else -1)))

(define (alignment-score s1 s2)
  (define min-length (min (string-length s1) (string-length s2)))
  (let loop ((score 0) (index 0))
    (if (= index min-length)
      score
      (loop (+ score (char-scorer (string-ref s1 index) (string-ref s2 index)))(+ index 1)))))
```

Comment: This seems very related (possible duplicate) of [Scheme - Help Writing A Function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23154180/1281433). The example inputs and outputs are pretty much the same, if not identical.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the operation into two steps.

1. Compute the maximum score. Here's a function that can do that.

   ```
   (define (get-maximum-score lst scoring-func)
    (apply max (map (lambda (x) (scoring-func (car x) (cadr x))) lst)))
   ```
2. Filter the list by selecting the items that match the maximum score and drop the rest.

   ```
   (define (get-maximum-score-items lst scoring-func)

     (define max-score (get-maximum-score lst scoring-func))

     (define (helper in out)
       (if (null? in)
         out
         (if (eq? max-score (scoring-func (caar in) (cadar in)))
           (helper (cdr in) (append out (list (car in))))
           (helper (cdr in) out))))

     (helper lst '())
     )
   ```

Now get the result.

```
(print
 (get-maximum-score-items
  '(("hello" "b_low") ("hello_" "b_l_ow") ("hello" "_blow") ("hello" "blow") ("h_e_llo" "bl_o__w"))
     alignment-score))
```

Comment: I tried that, and the say there's a wrong number of arguments passed to procedure? Am i suppose to add something else?

Comment: @Definer I had some typos in my answer. Try the functions again.

Comment: I still get an error kind Sir, it says Error in Map -- Wrong number of arguments passed to procedure (score-function '("hello" "b_low"))

Comment: @Definer Can you post your scoring function?

Comment: (define (scoring-function char1 char2)  
  (cond ((char=? char1 char2) 2) 
    ((or (char=? char1 #\_ ) (char=? #\_ char2)) -2)
    (else -1)))  **and also**  

  (define (alignment-score s1 s2)
  (define min-length (min (string-length s1) (string-length s2)))
  (let loop ((score 0) (index 0))
    (if (= index min-length) score(loop (+ score (scoring-function (string-ref s1 index)
             (string-ref s2 index)))(+ index 1)))))

Comment: @Definer I updated your post with the functions you provided and my answer to match those functions. It should work now.

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but when I execute it, nothing happens, the function just ends

Comment: @Definer sorry for the sloppy answers. It's fixed now. Give it another try.

Comment: no problem sir. It gives me output of hello_b_l_o_w6> now, prompting me to input again

Comment: @Definer Don't know how I can help any more. With your functions and my functions, I get the correct output - `(("hello" "b_low") ("hello_" "b_l_ow") ("hello" "_blow"))`

Comment: I renamed a few of my things, so maybe there's a bit confusion in that? Did you use my updated example?

Comment: Also, is your "scoring-func" refer to my "alignment-score"

Comment: Yes. The `print` function uses `alignment-score` to call `get-maximum-score-items`.

Comment: @ R Sahu , any idea why else it won't work? Maybe you could post or email me please?

Comment: I'm very confused on how to fix it, please help @R Sahu

Comment: Or maybe even post your and my version as one post please

Comment: @Definer I think it will be a disservice to you if I help you any more than I already have. You should be able to take it from here.